# Select records by comparing subsets

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Given two tables (the rows in each table are distinct):

```
 1)  x | y     z   2)  x | y     z
    -------   ---     -------   ---
     1 | a     a       1 | a     a
     1 | b     b       1 | b     b
     2 | a             1 | c
     2 | b             2 | a
     2 | c             2 | b
                       2 | c
```

Is there a way to select the values in the `x` column of the first table for which the subset of values in the `y` column, for that `x`, matches exactly the values in the `z` column of the second table?

In case `1)`, expected result is `1`. If `c` is added to the second table then the expected result is `2`.
In case `2)`, expected result is `no record` since neither of the subsets in the first table matches the subset in the second table. If `c` is added to the second table then the expected result is `1, 2`.

I've tried using `except` and `intersect` to compare subsets of first table with the second table, which works fine, but it takes too long on the `intersect` part and I can't figure out why (the first table has about 10.000 records and the second has around 10).

EDIT: I've updated the question to provide an extra scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT
  table1.x
FROM
  table1
INNER JOIN
  table2
    ON table1.y = table2.z
GROUP BY
  table1.x
HAVING
      COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 AS lookup)
  AND COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 AS lookup WHERE x = table1.x)
```

Comment: Doesn't work as desired: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d53d/1/0 (_"If c is added to the second table then the expected result is 2"_)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - You have a typo in your fiddle. You insert `a,c,c` for set 2 in table 1. It should be `a,b,c`.

Comment: This assumes that there are no duplicates in the tables, which isn't asserted

Comment: Shouldn't the count be on left side table? This way ABC will match AB because C record will not be counted.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović - Try it.

Comment: [I did - try this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc627/15). It returns both 1 and 2. But changed to `COUNT(DISTINCT table1.y)` works correctly.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović - Unfortunately my employer has IE6 and I can't get it to load.  I can only see the top 11 lines of the schema code.  I can take a look later today though.  But `COUNT(DISTINCT {a,b,NULL})` should return 2.

Comment: Exactly. But table1 has three records for x=2 and the count returns two, ignoring null, which (erroneously) equals number of records in table2. Uh, and I want to say that I'm not the downvoter. I've never downvoted.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović - Sorry, I was being slow!  Now corrected :)

Comment: I'm sorry for not finding better wording ;-)

Comment: @devnull - It's good that I'm going on holiday, I need it.  Sorry that I didn't think this through.  Here is what is needed for an exact match, and some examples: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/507e9/3

Answer (score 1):

One of these will do

```
select
    t1.x
from 
    table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2 on t1.x=t2.x
group by t1.x
having count(distinct t1.x)=count(distinct t2.x)

select
    t1.x
from 
    table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2 on t1.x=t2.x
group by t1.x
having count(distinct t1.x)=(select count(distinct x) from table2)
```

Comment: I Think It's not about the quantity, it's about to got the same data. In that example will work, but in a table with 10.000 records won't